# UILabel textRectForBounds not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to figure out the height of a long string "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen" as would be needed to fit in a multi-line UILabel.  The problem is that I am getting incorrect results from this method, even if I wait to call this method inside `layoutSubviews()`

```
let rect = label.textRectForBounds(
   CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: label.bounds.width, height: 10000000.0),
   limitedToNumberOfLines: 6)
```

When I set a breakpoint after this line, I get:

```
(lldb) po rect
▿ CGRect
  ▿ origin : CGPoint
    - x : 0.0
    - y : 0.0 { ... }
  ▿ size : CGSize
    - width : 374.0
    - height : 36.0
```

That 36.0 height is way to short -- that reprsents a single line, and I already have the label height set to be 65.0 so that two lines will display.  When displayed, the UILabel is three lines high and the text gets cut off because the height is not big enough:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Why can I not get the expected result of a height of 36.0*3=108.0?

For what it's worth, I get the same results if I call this method:

```
let rect = (label.text as NSString!).boundingRectWithSize(
   CGSize(width: label.bounds.width, height: 100000000.0), 
   options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, 
   attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], 
   context: NSStringDrawingContext())
```

**EDIT:** The problem did end up being that the view had not been laid out yet, causing the width of the UILabel to be incorrect in the calculation above.  See the last comment for details.

Comment: My first thought was layoutSubviews() also. How about trying things in the superview - viewWillLayoutSubviews()? viewDidLayoutSubviews()? Just a quick thought, probably won't help.

Comment: @dfd, This indeed solved the problem.  The real issue was the width of the label.  It had not been set yet, because the view had not yet been laid out (even in `layoutSubviews()`).  So the width  of 374.0 in my console shown in the question is really wide. After layout, this went down to 178.0.  This is why after layout the text fit in 3 lines and before layout it fit in 1 line.

Comment: I'm still rather new here. Should I post this as an answer?

Comment: Sure.  If you do I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when a view is a subview inside the view hierarchy, it's best to set height/width (using either frames or auto layout constraints) from the superview in **viewWillLayoutSubviews()** (or **viewDidLayoutSubviews()**).
Before these are executed the views don't have all the layout data they need.

Comment: The problem was that my UILabel had a width set by autolayout, and this width wasn't set until the parent container was laid out.   As a result, calculating the height before the parent was laid out was based on a placeholder width for the UILabel that was really wide, making the height calculation always come out to one line.   Once it was laid out, the width was much narrower, making the text take many more lines.  Only if I made the calculation after the width was set did I get the accurate number.